# Show that $M_2(\mathbb R)AM_2(\mathbb R)=M_2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. Show that $M_2(\mathbb R)AM_2(\mathbb R)=M_2(\mathbb R)$

Since $M_2(\mathbb R)AM_2(\mathbb R)$ is an ideal is it sufficient to show that it contains an invertible matrix (a unit) and is therefore equal to the whole ring?

Comment: What you you mean by $M_2(\mathbb R)AM_2(\mathbb R)$? If you mean the set of matrices of the form $XAY$ with $X,Y$ ranging over $M_2(\mathbb R)$, then that is not necessarily an ideal, because it is not closed under addition. Furthermore, it most certainly does not contain any invertible matrices because multiplying $A$ by any matrix (from left or righ) is not going to make its determinant non-zero.

Comment: The key to this is to understand that the ideal generated by $A$ consist of finite sums $\sum_i X_iAY_i$. You can move the $1$ around, and write $I_2$ in this form :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen This is standard notation in ring theory and the sums are implicit: $M_2(\mathbb{R})A M_2(\mathbb{R}) = \{\sum_i X_i A Y_i: \dots\}$.

Comment: Hmm? I would just call it the ideal generated by $A$ :-) I agree that $IJ$, when meaning the product of ideals $I$ and $J$ has those sums implicitly.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, it is probably safer to call it the (two-sided) ideal generated by $A$ :) But I think for example the well-known textbook of Dummit and Foote employs this notation.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Jacobson uses $(A)$ which is unambiguous, In the group side $HaH$ for example stands for a double coset rather than any generated structure.. I guess that is just one more reason I will never read D&F. The other reasons being that for them rings don't necessarily contain $1$ and that for them $D_n$ is NOT the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon.

Comment: But this exchange is becoming [too meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12938/11619) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an abstract answer:

It is a general fact that if $R$ is a ring, then the ideals of $M_n(R)$ are of the form $M_n(I)$ where $I$ is an ideal in $R$. Thus, $M_2(\mathbb{R})A M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is of the form $M_2(I)$ for an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$. However, the only ideals in $\mathbb{R}$ are $0$ and $\mathbb{R}$ itself, because every non-zero element is invertible. It thus follows that $M_2(\mathbb{R})A M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is either $M_2(0) = 0$ or $M_2(\mathbb{R})$. But $M_2(\mathbb{R})A M_2(\mathbb{R})$ contains the matrix $A$, so that it cannot be zero and thus it must be equal to all of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Basically, I used that if $R$ is a simple ring, then $M_n(R)$ is also a simple ring.

---

Here is a concrete answer:

Let $rE_{i,j}$ be the elementary matrix that is $r$ on position $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere. Note that $A= E_{1,1}$. It suffices to show that $M_2(\mathbb{R})A M_2(\mathbb{R})$ contains all these elementary matrices, because one can take their sums to obtain any other matrix. You can write every $r E_{i,j}$ in the form $X E_{1,1} Y$ for matrices $X,Y$, as an easy exercise in matrix calculations shows. For example
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0 & r \\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}0 & r \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response, but we haven’t learnt that property yet. Does what I’ve said make any sense?

Comment: @Loobear23 Don't worry. I edited my answer to give an elementary approach. And yes it does, finding an invertible element would be enough but it is equally easy to find that you find generators inside your ideal.